# Handling Push Notification

Tags: iphone, push-notification

What is the best way to handle push notification when the application is running and if I want to return back to the current view after showing the notification view?

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIAlertView or push your notification on top of the UINavigationController stack that most applications use.

Or roll your own popup.  You can model it on one of several public domain implementations such as https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView